# How to set the --nocapture flag for all Rust/Cargo tests in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, clion, rust-cargo

Is there a way to make IntelliJ's/CLion's Rust plugin use the `--nocapture` flag for Rust tests?

I see I could create a "Run" configuration for each test, but that's not scalable.

Also, IntelliJ used to print the Cargo command it was running for tests.  Now the output window just shows `Testing started at 15:31 ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customise the template for all configurations. Please enable `Show stdout/stderr in tests (and disable tool window)` option on the `Run | Edit Configurations` tab: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVEan.png)

Comment: I'm not seeing this option on CLion 2023.1.2 on Mac.

Answer (score 1):

For command line usage add an alias:

```
.cargo/config:

[alias]
t = "test -- --nocapture"
```

run with:

```
$ cargo t
```

Or to preserve color:

```
[alias]
t = "test -- --nocapture --color always"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately The current Intellij Rust plugin provides no way to set `--nocapture` flag in the run templates.

However there is another much better way to achieve the goal. Set the `RUST_TEST_NOCAPTURE` env variable to anything other than `0` in the configuration template, and you will have the output as it occurs. You dont need the `--nocapture` flag.

[image]

Ref: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/tests/index.html#--nocapture